# @PrePersist Annotation in Hibernate 6.3.1.Final not working for @EmbeddedId

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I upgrade an application to spring-boot 3.2.0-RC2, that uses hibernate-core: 6.3.1.Final as dependency.
from spring boot: 3.1.5 with hibernate-core: 6.2.13.Final.

In the entities I am using the @PrePersists methode for generating an EmbeddedId.

With hibernate 6.3.1.Final the following exception occurs:

`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Null id generated for entity 'com.example.demoembedded.TestEntity'`

Example:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TestId id;


    @PrePersist
    private void prePersists() {
        id = new TestId(LocalDateTime.now().toString() + "asdasdad");
    }
}
```

The first test(testEntityWithEmbeddedId) fails with hibernate 6.3.1.Final with the following exception:

`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Null id generated for entity 'com.example.demoembedded.TestEntity'`

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
class DemoembeddedApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityRepo testEntityRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ThirdRepo thirdRepo;

    @Test
    void testEntityWithEmbeddedId() {
        TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
        TestEntity save = testEntityRepo.save(testEntity);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(save.getId());
    }

    @Test
    void thirdEntityWithLongId() {
        ThirdEntity thirdEntity = new ThirdEntity();
        ThirdEntity save = thirdRepo.save(thirdEntity);
    }

}
```

The second test(thirdEntityWithLongId) works with hibernate-core:6.2.13.Final and with 6.3.1.Final.

Any idea how to solve this problem?